# How to install php soap with rpm packages in centos 6.4 x86_64

Tags: linux, installation, centos, php, rpm

I want to install php-soap, centos says:

```
[root@LMS-Cent64 soap]# rpm -ivh php-soap-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64.rpm error: Failed dependencies:
        php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-22.el6 is needed by php-soap-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64
```

after installing php-common(x86-64):

```
[root@LMS-Cent64 soap]# rpm -ivh php-common-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64.rpm Preparing...               
########################################### [100%]
        package php-common-5.3.3-23.el6_4.x86_64 (which is newer than php-common-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64) is already installed
        file /usr/lib64/php/modules/phar.so from install of php-common-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php-common-5.3.3-23.el6_4.x86_64
```

What to do now?

Answer (score 1):

If possible, use yum to update all your packages, and then use yum to install php-soap.

If you must install from an rpm, install php-soap-5.3.3-23.el6_4.x86_64 which is in the CentOS repo.  Really should let yum or the graphical package manager handle all this for you though.